# MVC - loading JQuery Tabs on click of a button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC and JQuery. My requirement is simple. I have 3 tabs, the 1st one has couple of date picker fields and a button. 2nd and 3rd tabs displays graph based on the date selected. What i need is to populate the 2nd and 3rd graph (Image) when I click button in the first tab.

Here is the content of my aspx file
    
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#EndDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
 </script>

<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-DS">Data Selection</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-CI">Carbon Impact</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#tabs-ED">Energy Demand</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-DS">
 <p> Trial </p>
         <select trialname="SMTrial">
          <option value="SMR">Residential Smart Metering</option>
         </select>

         <p></p>
            <% Html.BeginForm("GetSmartMeterData", "Trials");%>
                <p>Start Date</p>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate , new { style = "width:100px" })%>

                <p>End Date</p>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { style = "width:100px" })%>

                <input type="button" id="but1" value="Go" onclick="location.href='<%:Url.Action("GetSmartMeterData", "Chart") %>'" />

            <% Html.EndForm();%>


        </div>
        <div id="tabs-CI">

        </div>
        <div id="tabs-ED">

        </div>
 </div>
```

With this code when i click button, it just plots the graph on a blank page but I want it to render inside my Tab "tabs-CI".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% Ajax.BeginForm("GetSmartMeterData", "Chart", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "tabs-CI" });%>
     <p>Start Date</p>
     <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate , new { style = "width:100px" })%>

     <p>End Date</p>
     <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { style = "width:100px" })%>

     <input type="submit" id="but1" value="Go" />

<% Ajax.EndForm();%>
```

Comment: I tried the above method. Now, tabs are seen after I click the button but no graph is displayed inside the tab.

Comment: No graph or nothing is displayed inside the tab?

Comment: Nothing is displayed inside the tab

Comment: You have to switch to tab 'tabs-CI', and where do you initialize jQuery tabs?

Comment: use `$('#tabs').tabs()` to initialize tabs

Comment: Yes, I'm initializing the tabs as below and I did switch to 'tabs-CI'  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>

Comment: No, I don't see any error ( I take you are talking about error that is displayed at the bottom left corner of IE )

Comment: Karaxuna - I tried putting a break point at function "GetSmartMeterData" with your proposed code (UpdateTargetId) but button click event isn't hitting the break point.

Comment: @RaviGowda Then there has to be error in console. open site with chrome and open developer tools with F12, there is console and errors log there

Comment: Hmmm, I opened the site with chrome. pressed 'F12' after clicking the button in first tab. I don't see anything under the console tab (just blank and control still not hitting the break point).

Comment: oops, sorry Karaxuna, I'm getting some syntax error. Will see to it and update you the outcome

Comment: Now I got rid of the syntax error. Console not showing any error now. Still the same result ( not hitting the break point ) :(

Comment: When ajax request is sent to controller action and break point does not work it may mean 2 things: 1. something wrong with routes or parameters (in this case there will be error logged in console that server responded with status code [code]), 2. It is returning blank page before reaching action (in some action filter). Or you may not run application in debug mode :D Or maybe another action is called with same name and different http method

Comment: My controller function "GetSmartMeterData" does not take any parameter. Is your code still holds good ? ---> "Ajax.BeginForm("GetSmartMeterData", "Chart", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = "tabs-CI" });%>"

Comment: Thanks karaxuna for all your answers. My view page is aspx page. Will this cause any problems in getting this work ?

Comment: @RaviGowda no, it must not cause any problems as far as I know